# Angular Material Table not displaying data from API service

Tags: angular-material

I've checked the other questions on this topic here but none seemed to solve my problem. I'm pulling a list of noticeboard notices from an API as an observable and trying to display them in a table. The table headers render but no rows. I can get the data to render if I use Pre tags and the variable but assigning it to dataSource isn't working - and no errors.

Service snippet

```
getObjectWithParams(object: any, params: any): Observable<any> {
        this.ResourcePath = object;
        const NewQueryOptions = this.QueryOptions + params;
        return this.http.get(`${this.ServiceRoot}${this.ResourcePath}${NewQueryOptions}`, { 'headers': this.headers });
    }
```

notices.component.ts

```
export class NoticesComponent implements OnInit {
  
  public notices!: INotice[];
  
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['ReleaseDate', 'ReleaseTag','Status', 'Title']
  dataSource!: MatTableDataSource<INotice>;

  pageSize   = 10;
  pageIndex  = 0;
  pageLength = 0;
  
  private _top: number | undefined;
  private _skip: number | undefined;

  constructor( private OData: ODataService, private _location: Location) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
   this.getNotices('/notices', '$count=true&$top=10'); 
}

public getNotices(table: string, params: string) {
  this.OData.getObjectWithParams(table, params)
    .subscribe( data =>  {
      this.notices = data,
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<INotice>(this.notices);
    }); 
  }
}
```

notices.component.html

```
<Div *ngIf="dataSource">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8" matSort>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="ReleaseDate">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Release Date </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let notice"> {{notice.ReleaseDate}} </td>
            </ng-container>
        
            <ng-container matColumnDef="ReleaseTag">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Release Tag </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let notice"> {{notice.ReleaseTag}} </td>
            </ng-container>
        
            <ng-container matColumnDef="Status">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Status </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let notice"> {{notice.Status}} </td>
            </ng-container>
              
            <ng-container matColumnDef="Title">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Title </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let notice"> {{ notice.Title}}</td>
            </ng-container>
    
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
    <!--<pre> {{ notices | json }}</pre> -->
</Div>
```

I'm hoping another set of eyes may spot the issue easily so appreciate any insights in what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: can you please add response so it will be more clear

Comment: HI @KiranMistry, apologies, I thought I'd mentioned it. The response is the page rendered with the table title but no rows displayed (not even blank rows - just nothing). No errors in console. Can see the data from the API in the network tab on the dev tools and as per the pre tags in the HTML file above if I uncomment that out the data is displayed form the the notices variable.

Suspect the dataSource isn't getting the data but not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a problem with response parsing.

```js
public getNotices(table: string, params: string) {
  this.OData.getObjectWithParams(table, params)
    .subscribe( response =>  {
      this.notices = response.data, //this is actual response object
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<INotice>(this.notices);
    }); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Rushit. I don't think this is the problem.

When I make this change I don't get any compile errors however I still don't see any rows in the table. If I uncomment the Pre tag, I no longer see the variable data either.

From what I can work out I'm getting the response back okay but it's not getting into the dataSource variable and then rendered on the page.

Comment: @leadfollowmove can you please share response snapshot.

Comment: might be a step close. If I use 
`console.log('API response: ' + JSON.stringify(response) )`
I can see the JSON formatted payload back from the API. If I duplicate this row for the dataSource I get an error: ERROR TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Answer (score 0):

Thanks To @Rushit and @Kiran for the input. It was enough to make me dig deeper in the code and I found the issue.

I hadn't realised that the OData service wasn't removing some OData decorators on the return data which was messing up further manipulation.

As an FYI to anyone else this was how I solved it:

Corrected the OData Service to remove metadata using a QueryOptions variable

```
public QueryOptions = '?$format=application/json;odata.metadata=none'
...
     getObjectWithParams(object: any, params: any): Observable<any> {
        this.ResourcePath = object;
        const NewQueryOptions = this.QueryOptions + params;
        return this.http.get(`${this.ServiceRoot}${this.ResourcePath}${this.QueryOptions}`, { 'headers': this.headers });
    }
```

And then as Rushit pointed out the input needed adjusting from response to response.value:

```
public getNotices(table: string, params: string) {
  this.OData.getObjectWithParams(table, params)
    .subscribe( response =>  {
      this.notices = response.value,
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<INotice>(this.notices);
    }); 
  }
}
```